# How can we - Redirect to object list view from VF in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-ready, visualforce-in-lightning

I tried this but it is not working in Lightning Experience

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.List,$ObjectType.Account)}}" target="_blank">
     View All Accounts
</apex:outputLink>
```

Found details around global variable **Action** here - [Redirecting to a Standard Object List Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_override_list_page.htm) but even it didn't help much

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail than "it is not working"?

Answer (score 1):

`<outputlink/>` would translate to classic URL which doesn't work in Lightning or it redirect to classic user interface.

In Lightning, navigation does not vary org to org. You only need to pass the Sobject name only. 
For Account just set up the url as:

> `/one/one.app?source=aloha#/sObject/Account/home`